# value of data-* is wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm creating a radio button with jquery, for each radio button i'm passing informations like (title , descriptions.. ) so i use data- attributs for that. 
here is my code :

```
 $("#tableaudesdocs").append("<td><input type='radio' data- 
 title="+a.Documents[i].s_title +" name='radio'> </td>");
```

The problem is that the value of data-title is wrong( he take juste a first part of the real value), for exemple if i have the title: my title , it will show me juste my , when i inspect element in the browser i have this result :

```
 <input type='radio' data-title='my' title+ name='radio'>
```

Any One of you have an idea about that .

Comment: can you show output of `console.log(a.Documents[i].s_title);`

Comment: 1. put it in quotes 2. actually, don't do that. Use `.data()`

Comment: this should work: `("#tableaudesdocs").append("<td><input type='radio' data- 
 title='" + a.Documents[i].s_title + "' name='radio'> </td>");`. You forgot single quotes between the `data-title` value.

Comment: this `title="+a.Documents[i].s_title + "` will be `title=Whatever this is` without any apostrophes or quotes hence it only shows first part that's adjecent to `=` and use rest as attributes

Comment: _"Any One of you have an idea about that"_ -> https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Template literals could also make this easier to read, if you are able to have browser support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include **single quotes** (i.e `'` character) between the value of the `data-title` attribute, your code should be fixed to this:

```
$("#tableaudesdocs").append("<td><input type='radio' data-title='" + a.Documents[i].s_title + "' name='radio'> </td>");
```

Check next example showing the correct usage:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var title = "My title";

    $("#tableaudesdocs").append("<td><input type='radio' data-title='" + title  + "' name='radio'>DATA</td>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tableaudesdocs">
</table>
```